# SQL- How to exclude wrong time(saved in form of nvarchar) in my dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I am trying to convert records in form of nvarchar into time. For example:
`1520` into `15:20:0000`
But it throws error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Because there are wrong timestamps in the dataset like values:

```
4059','7054','4054','4030','3040','6046','7555','8030', '1169'
```

I am using the query:

```
select [QHHHMM],
    cast(SUBSTRING([QHHHMM], 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING([QHHHMM], 3, 2)  as time) as TimeHistory
FROM [MOCK124].[dbo].[F2QH]
where 
[QHHHMM] not in ('4059','7054','4054','4030','3040','6046','7555','8030')
and [QHHHMM] not in ('1169')
```

But I still see there are few more records that are invalid as time. Could anyone please assist what should be the where clause to exclude all the invalid timestamps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at the hours/mins as integers?

```
where cast(left(QHHHMM, 2) as int) between 0 and 23
  and cast(right(QHHHMM, 2) as int) between 0 and 59
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out, we can use 
 where
   [QHHHMM] > '2359' 
    or
     substring([QHHHMM], 3,2) > '59'

Thanks!